# FacebookSDK (php) cant recognize '#' character in multiqueries calls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Im having a strange error with Facebok PHP SDK. Im trying to get a list of friends based in the first character's names and the images of their profiles.

My function to look for "john" friends looks like this:

```
public function searchFriends($fbToken, $search) {
    # atualizar a api do facebook com o token de acesso:
    $this->facebookAPI->setAccessToken($token);

    $multiquery = array(
        "q1" => 'SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND strpos(lower(name), "john") = 0',
        "q2" => "SELECT url FROM profile_pic WHERE width = 32 AND height = 32 AND id in #q1"
    );

    $send = array();
    $send['method'] = 'fql.multiquery';
    $send['queries'] = $multiquery;
    $send['callback'] = '';

    $friends = $this->facebookAPI->api($send);

    return $friends;
}
```

The error im getting is:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 601: Parser error: unexpected '#q1' at position 71. thrown in /nfs/c03/h03/mnt/55868/domains/secure.thegoodfellas.com.br/html/tamojuntometro/php/fb/base_facebook.php on line 1252**

It looks like the FacebookAPI dont recognizes the "#" character wich refers to the first query. Does anyone have a clue on this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error.

The problem was with my second query:

From

"q2" => "SELECT url FROM profile_pic WHERE width = 32 AND height = 32 AND **id in #q1**"

TO

"q2" => "SELECT url FROM profile_pic id in **(SELECT id in #q1)**"